# Python 3: How Do I Invert A Dictionary That Has A List As A Value

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

So for class I need to take a dictionary that has a list as a value and invert it. I have found several ways to do this, but the issue is when there are non-unique values. I found a way to do this but I feel like there must be much easier and streamlined ways to do this.

```
summon_locations = {
  "Solaire": ['Gargoyles' ,'Gaping Dragon', "Ornstein/Smough"],
  "Gotthard": ['Abyss Watchers' ,'Pontiff Sulyvahn', "Grand Archives"],
  "Lucatiel": ['Lost Sinner', 'Smelter Demon', 'The Rotten'],
}
#Original dictionary


summon_locations = {
  "Solaire": ['Gargoyles' ,'Gaping Dragon', "Ornstein/Smough"],
  "Gotthard": ['Abyss Watchers' ,'Pontiff Sulyvahn', "Grand Archives"],
  "Lucatiel": ['Lost Sinner', 'Smelter Demon', 'Abyss Watchers'],
}

#Dictionary with a non-unique value

def invert(d):
    big_dict = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        for i in v:
            if i not in big_dict:
                big_dict[i] = [k]
            else:
                big_dict[i].append(k)
    return big_dict

print(invert(summon_locations))
```

**Output Original:**

{'Gargoyles': ['Solaire'], 'Gaping Dragon': ['Solaire'], 'Ornstein/Smough': ['Solaire'], 'Abyss Watchers': ['Gotthard'], 'Pontiff Sulyvahn': ['Gotthard'], 'Grand Archives': ['Gotthard'], 'Lost Sinner': ['Lucatiel'], 'Smelter Demon': ['Lucatiel'], 'The Rotten': ['Lucatiel']}

**Output One non-unique value:**

{'Gargoyles': ['Solaire'], 'Gaping Dragon': ['Solaire'], 'Ornstein/Smough': ['Solaire'], 'Abyss Watchers': ['Gotthard', 'Lucatiel'], 'Pontiff Sulyvahn': ['Gotthard'], 'Grand Archives': ['Gotthard'], 'Lost Sinner': ['Lucatiel'], 'Smelter Demon': ['Lucatiel']}

So it will just take the original key of a duplicate value and append it to a list. I have seen some cool ways to go about inverting dictionaries but they tend to fail here due to the lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to remove the else statement and to check if the key exists. If it doesn't exists an empty list will be created.

```
from pprint import pprint

summon_locations = {
    "Solaire": ['Gargoyles', 'Gaping Dragon', "Ornstein/Smough"],
    "Gotthard": ['Abyss Watchers', 'Pontiff Sulyvahn', "Grand Archives"],
    "Lucatiel": ['Lost Sinner', 'Smelter Demon', 'Abyss Watchers'],
}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from collections import defaultdict

    inverted = defaultdict(list)

    for key, values in summon_locations.items():
        for value in values:
            inverted[value].append(key)

    pprint(inverted)
```

Output

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'Abyss Watchers': ['Gotthard', 'Lucatiel'],
             'Gaping Dragon': ['Solaire'],
             'Gargoyles': ['Solaire'],
             'Grand Archives': ['Gotthard'],
             'Lost Sinner': ['Lucatiel'],
             'Ornstein/Smough': ['Solaire'],
             'Pontiff Sulyvahn': ['Gotthard'],
             'Smelter Demon': ['Lucatiel']})
```

Which is similar to the the one-liner

```
[inverted[value].append(key) for key, values in summon_locations.items() for value in values]
```

But one liners are not always better, in this case I would stay with the two for loops.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. Now I just need to reverse engineer this so I can remember it.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your if else :

```
def invert(d):
    big_dict = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        for i in v:
            big_dict[i] = big_dict.get(i, []) + [k]
    return big_dict
```

However I can't find a way to skip one for.